# Select Where Result Is In String

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I would like to perform a SQL Select Statement where any text in the query is a result.

For example, if the query is 'Driving Directions to Dundee in Scotland' I want this result to be returned

```
id: 5
name: Dundee
description: Dundee is a City in Scotland
Location: 56.4640° N, 2.9700° W
```

Comment: Expecting further elaboration.

Comment: And your question about that broad task is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your particular example, you could use this `where` clause:

```
where $query like concat('%', name, '%')
```